# $e^{jwt}$ is an ortho-normal basis proof

Tags: harmonic-functions, orthonormal

I'd like to know how one is supposed to show that the set $ \{ e^{jwt} \}$, where $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$ , is an ortho-normal basis?

So actually, how do I show that for every  $w_1 \neq w_2 $:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{jw_1t}e^{-jw_2t}dt=0$ ?

Kindly

Sammy

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! Are you sure the bounds are $+\infty$ and $-\infty$?

Comment: Not entirely actually. How do I know which boundaries to choose in order to show orthogonality for this specific set of functions? I have a feeling that its the [-$\pi$,$\pi$] interval...

Comment: Yes, I would compute it over a period.

Answer (score 0):

Note first that if $R\in\Bbb R^+$ and $\omega\ne0$,$$\int_{-R}^R\exp(j\omega t)dt=\left[\frac{1}{j\omega}\exp(j\omega t)\right]_{-R}^R=\frac{2\sin(\omega R)}{\omega}=2R\operatorname{sinc}(\omega R).$$The final expression is also valid if $\omega=0$. Since $\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{sinc}(\omega)$ is a nascent delta function,$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(j\omega t)dt=2\pi\delta(\omega).$$In particular,$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\overline{\exp(j\omega_1t)}\exp(j\omega_2t)dt=2\pi\delta(\omega_1-\omega_2)$$(in your question, you forgot one factor in the integrand should be complex-conjugated). This is our orthonormality condition (well, if we divide each basis element by $\sqrt{2\pi}$).

Comment: Thank you for the answer' but would you be kind enough to explain the right hand side of the following equation:
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp(j\omega t)dt=2\pi\delta(\omega)$ ?

Comment: @SammyAspel Are you familiar with [nascent delta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Approximations_to_the_identity)? If so, I'm setting $\epsilon=1/R$.